# objective-c,How to send file as a parameter

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to upload my image from my phone gallery to the server so I am not able to upload my program ,it runs successfully and shows print -

```
NSLog(@">>>>>>>>>> enter in ");
```

but it could not upload image on the server ,when I checked it in the app then there is no image ,and I also checked parameter, I think I am not sending proper file format in the parameter.
Please can anyone help me with proper file formate how to convert it

`

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
        didFinishPickingImage:(UIImage *)img
                  editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editingInfo
{
    [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    NSURL *imagePath = [editingInfo objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL"];
    imageName = [imagePath lastPathComponent];
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

    localFilePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:imageName];

    NSLog(@"localFilePath.%@",localFilePath);
}

 - (IBAction)submitBtn:(id)sender 
{
    NSURL* url;
    url = [NSURL URLWithString:UrlBasic];
    AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [[AFHTTPSessionManager alloc] initWithBaseURL:url];

    manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializerWithWritingOptions:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted];
    manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializerWithReadingOptions:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments];
    manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes setByAddingObject:@"text/html"];

    fileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:localFilePath];
    reqData=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:imageName1,@"image",@"addclassphotoactmobs",@"droot",schoolFolderA,@"schoolfolder",_choseGalleryTextF.text,@"gname",dividNum,@"classid",fileURL,@"uploadedfile",nil];
    NSLog(@"reqData=%@",reqData);

    [manager POST:UrlBasic parameters:reqData constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) { }
             progress:nil 
              success:^(NSURLSessionTask *task, NSMutableDictionary *responseObject) {
        NSLog(@" %@",responseObject);
        NSLog(@">>>>>>>>>> enter in ");

        [self.view makeToast:@"submitted  ....."
                    duration:3.0
                    position:CSToastPositionCenter];
    } failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"error-=%@",error);
        //  [self.view makeToast:@"Please check internet connection !"];
    }];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Updated with imageNameStr]

While uploading your image data, it is necessary to send Name of the file.To generate a file Name, Here I've used Date and time.

Add the Code below the Line `NSLog(@"reqData=%@",reqData);`

====================

You have missed the formData Code.
Where as the image is the actual image in the below code.

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyyMMddhhmmssSSS"];
NSString *imageNameStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.jpg",[formatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]]];

[sessionManager POST:appendURL
              parameters:postParamDict
constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData)

     {
         if(image!=nil){
             NSData * imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image,0.5f);

             if(imageData!=nil){
                 [formData appendPartWithFileData:imageData
                                             name:@"image"
                                         fileName:imageNameStr
                                         mimeType:@"image/jpg"];
             }
         }
     }
    progress:^(NSProgress * _Nonnull uploadProgress) {
    }
    success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nonnull task, id  _Nonnull responseObject) {

                     NSLog(@"%@",responseObject);
                     if(success)
                         success (responseObject);


    }
    failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nullable task, NSError * _Nonnull error) {

                     NSLog(@"error %@",error);
                     if(failure)
                         failure (error);
    }]
```

Comment: Hello Vicky ! Thanks for your answer ,but I am confused in fileName:imageNameStr  what should and how should I pass my file name !

Comment: @sumitakatkar check the answer now, I've updated it !

Comment: 'this error comes :- 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSPathStore2 CGImage]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x608000449990'